# Which changes take precedence between updating commit message via git and updating diff vs editing revision in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I've noticed I can edit a Phabricator diff's summary field directly from the web app without having to update the git commit and then updating the diff, but it's not clear to me which changes take precedence. If I Edit Revision via the web app and later land the diff, will those changes get overwritten by the latest git commit message?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `arc amend` to update the commit message locally based on what phabricator has recorded in differential. I think this is also ran before landing so it should update your local commit message if you change things in the web UI. I don't think the same is true in reverse, however. If you later update the commit message locally after submitting to differential, arc amend will overwrite your changes with the message from differential.